# HP Printer Envy 5660 Prints Discoloration

Tags: printing, printer, network-printer

asking for some help to troubleshoot my printer before I go ahead and buy a new one. Is there anything I'm failing to consider here?

Situation:

- When I print black/white pages of text it is discolored.
- I see a paper in the rear that makes me thing there is a jam. Though my printer can make print attempts.
- I ran through the diagnostic and self cleaning tests - same results.
- My ink levels seem fine.
- I submitted a post on the HP support site - I can't speak to their techs as their platform won't recognize my device's serial number.

Perceived Problem:

- Unknown.

Ink levels:
[image: Ink levels.]

what seems to be a paper jam:
[image: what seems to be a paper jam]

print quality test result:
[image: print quality test result]

Comment: Have you followed the instructions in [HP DeskJet, ENVY 5640, 5660 Printers - 'Paper Jam' Error](https://support.hp.com/gb-en/document/c04759464)?

Comment: The printer may have a hardware problem causing this (likely I think)